# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: get wrong values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I tried to create an abstract model, but I have an error in
this *abstract.php* file:

```
public function create()
{
    global $connection;
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . static::$tableName . ' SET ' . self::buildNameParameterSQL();
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);

    foreach(static::$tableSchema as $col=>$type){

        if($type == 4){
           $sanitizedValue = filter_var($this->$col, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
           $stmt->bindValue(":{$col}", $sanitizedValue);
        }
        else{
            $stmt->bindValue(":{$col}", $this->$col, $type); // Error here
        }
    }
    return $stmt->execute();
}
```

And here is my class employee in employee.php that extends this abstract model:

```
require_once 'abstract.php';

cLass Employee extends AbstractModel
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $age;
    private $address;
    private $tax;
    private $salary;


    protected static $tableName = 'employees';
    protected static $tableSchema = array (
        'name' => self::DATA_TYPE_STR,
        'age' => self::DATA_TYPE_INT,
        'address' => self::DATA_TYPE_STR,
        'tax' => self::DATA_TYPE_DECIMAL,
        'salary' => self::DATA_TYPE_DECIMAL
    );

    public function __construct($name, $age, $address, $tax, $salary){

        global $connection;

        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->address = $address;
        $this->tax = $tax;
        $this->salary = $salary;
    }
```

And when I created a new object of class employee and invoke a created method

```
<?php
    require_once ('db.php');
    require_once ('employee.php');

    $emp = new Employee("abanoub", 21, "Cairo, Egypt", 1.03, 5000);
    var_dump($emp->create());
```

And here my error

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ': name, address =: address, salary =: salary, tax =: tax, age =: age' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\pdo\abstract.php:47 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\pdo\abstract.php(47): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\pdo\test.php(6): AbstractModel->create() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\pdo\abstract.php on line 47

Comment: There a capital "L" in 'class': `cLass Employee extends AbstractModel`. Does PHP have case-insensitive keywords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like spaces are rendered at the wrong place

`'name =: name, address =: address, salary =: salary, tax =: tax, age =: age'`

should be `'name = :name, address = :address, salary = :salary, tax = :tax, age = :age'`